# Why are many small files slower written as one large file on an USB flash drive

Tags: ssd, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

Suppose, you need to write **2000 files each 1 MByte** and **one file of 2 GByte**.

In general, writing the big file takes far less time than writing the small files.

> Q: But why take many files vs. one file am totally the same size much
> more time?

Often, I use an USB drive to transfer stuff one my dev machine to the production machine. In these cases, it would be nice, if writing thousands of files would be fast too.

Thus my idea:

> How about a USB drive file system, that writes many small files
> internally as one single big file. And finally write the directory of
> the 'file bundle'.
> Wouldn't such a file system be like a tape drive on disk?

Does such a file system exist?

Moreover, it would be even fine for me, if the FS would just write stuff the fastest way. Using probably more space as needed, but lees time to complete. Regenerating space may be done the drive is idle.

Answer (score 1):

To explain this in rather a Douglas Adams fashion.

Large file…

"Are you there?"
"Yup"
"Cool. File coming up. Ready to accept?"
Sure"
"Here we go…
*data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data data*
Did you get that?"
"Yup"
"Cool"

Small files…

"Are you there?"
"Yup"
"Cool. File coming up. Ready to accept?"
Sure"
"Here we go…
*data*
Did you get that?"
"Yup"
"Cool"
…
"Are you there?"
"Yup"
"Cool. File coming up. Ready to accept?"
Sure"
"Here we go…
*data*
Did you get that?"
"Yup"
"Cool"
… … … repeat ad-nauseum.

In short, it spends more time checking than writing. There's not really any way round that.
You could weigh up whether it would be quicker to compress it first, then copy just the one file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but there are numerous solutions to this problem - unfortunately some of the better ones are OS dependent.

You can, on Unix like systems mount a file as a disk, which wpilf solve your problem. I'm not sure if this is easily doable in Windows though.

You can look to something like Veracrypt to affect the above idea in a cross-platform way  - but, of-course you are introducing encryption and need that software.

Writing a file bundle can be done with something like zip, arm, 7z or tar.  These will also reduce the archive size further reducing disk IO on the USB key. Unfortunately modifying these archives can be frustrating and not really practical.